# How to inline css in vite2

Tags: javascript, postcss, vite

I use vite2 to build my app, and it's build a css file in my project. I want to get inline css in my project.(like postcss.config `extract: false`)
I tried:

```js
{
  css: { postcss: { extract: false } }
}
```

It didn't works.

I tried config postcss plugins directly:

```js
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        use: {
          less: { javascriptEnabled: true },
        },
        extensions: ['.less'],
        extract: false,
      }),
    ],
  }
},
```

And it can't recognized less file. 
I got this error:

```
[postcss] Unrecognised input
file: /Users/tang/Desktop/mono-repo/packages/editor/src/index.less
error during build:
undefined
```